# How to change style with setTimeout in Javascript

Tags: javascript

**(?)** I want to change my class name **'box'** from opacity '0' to opacity '1.0' like an animation or fade in every sec 1000ms, 2000ms. 3000ms,

**(X)** But **I don't want** to do something like this code but appears fade in like this [Code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/packy/wvutLag3/5/) and ***not* fade in at the same** time like this [Code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/packy/f6wd9m0j/152/).

```
var DivB = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
setTimeout(function(){DivB[0].style.opacity = "1"}, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){DivB[1].style.opacity = "1"}, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){DivB[2].style.opacity = "1"}, 3000);
```

**(/)** I want to make It appears with the delays 1000,2000,3000 with javascript look shorter like using var 'i' to javascript like this .. [Code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/packy/gasz7n98/16/).

```
var DivB = document.getElementsByClassName("box"); 
var i;

function myFade(){
for (var i=0; i<DivB.length; i++){
setTimeout(function(){DivR[i].style.opacity="1"}, i*1000)}
}

myFade();
```

Comment: Do you know about `setInterval()` too? And then you can stop it after a few runs using `clearInterval()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `setInterval`

```
var DivB = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
var divIndex = 0;
var interval = setInterval(() => {
  DivB[divIndex].style.opacity = "1";
  divIndex++;
  if (divIndex === divB.length - 1) clearInterval(interval);
} , 1000)
```

Basically, this will fire every one second, setting the opacity of `divB[divIndex]` to `'1'`. `divIndex` itself increments every interval as well. After all the **DivB** elements are processed, the interval will be cleared.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `transition: all 1s;` to the box CSS from one of the code examples you posted:

```js
var DivB = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

setTimeout(function(){DivB[0].style.opacity = "1"}, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){DivB[1].style.opacity = "1"}, 2000);  
setTimeout(function(){DivB[2].style.opacity = "1"}, 3000);
```

```css
.box { display:inline-block; position:relative; opacity:0; 

transition: all 1s;}
```

```html
<div class='box'>1</div><br/>
<div class='box'>2</div><br/>
<div class='box'>3</div><br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```js
var DivB = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

function myFade() {
  for (let i = 0; i < DivB.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      DivB[i].style.opacity = "1"
    }, i * 1000)
  }
}

myFade();
```

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>1</div>
<div class='box'>2</div>
<div class='box'>3</div>
```

I would suggest you to read the difference between `var` and `let` specially when using in loops with `setTimeout` and `setInterval`

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```js
function fadeElementsProgressive(className, timePerElement = 1000) {
 const divs = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  
  for(let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
   setTimeout(() => {
     divs[i].style.opacity = 1;
    }, i * timePerElement)
  }
}

fadeElementsProgressive('box');
```

```css
.box { display:inline-block; position:relative; opacity:0; }
```

```html
<div class='box'>1</div><br/>
<div class='box'>2</div><br/>
<div class='box'>3</div><br/>
```

This will create a function that get a class name and execute a fade.